# Visual Studio 2019 New Project does not include SSIS, whcih is installed

Tags: ssis, project, visual-studio-2019

I can open, edit and deploy existing SSIS projects in Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.0), but cannot see SQL Server Integration Services or related items in the list of available templates when I add a new project. I do not know why this is, since SQL Server Integration Services Projects is installed, and I think that is all I need. I am seeking Advice on how to make SSIS appear in the list of templates.

Edit: I also searched the following terms with no luck: SSIS, SSDT, Business, SQL, Intelligence

Demonstration that SQL Server Integration Services Projects is installed:

[image: Demonstration that SQL Server Integration Services Projects is installed]

Demonstration that I cannot see the related templates in the list when adding a new project:

[image]

Comment: Look under Workload -> Data Storage and Processing .  Is the option "SQL Server Data Tools" checked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please make sure that you have the latest extension installed, which can be downloaded from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

I checked and I am able to see the template searching for both integration and ssis:
[image]

Comment: I see in the link you supply, under Common Issues: `• There is a regression in VS2019 16.6 that SSIS project templates cannot be searched with keywords in create new project window. VS team is working on the fix.` It looks like I have fallen foul of that issue to me.  *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find it by searching for `Integration`, did you try `SSIS`? Microsoft has a steps process here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-1-1-creating-a-new-integration-services-project?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I did; sorry, I should have mentioned and will edit the question. I searched for SSIS, SSDT, Business, SQL and Intelligence

Comment: I had already seen the link (thanks for adding, though; that's certainly where anyone would hope to find the answer), but that refers to an older version of VS, with the Business Intelligence node and assumes that it is found in the list.

Comment: Actually, the answer assumes that you installed SSDT with a VS instance called SSDT, where VS was not previouslyinstalled.. Its something I first saw on 2017.